# Arreglo de números primos

Tags: array, c

Tengo que almacenar los 10 primeros números primos en un arreglo, ya hice el código para calcularlos pero no he conseguido lograr que se guarden en cada una de las posiciones del arreglo.

El código que tengo hasta el momento es este, se supone que ya calcula los primos, en arreglo lo tengo de 5 para no ver tantos valores nada más.

int main (){

```
int VecPrimos[5];
int j=0;
int cont=0;
int i=0;
for(i=2;i<12;i++){
for(j=2;j<=i;j++)
    if(i%j==0)
    cont++;
    if(cont==1)
    printf("\nEl numero primo es %d ",i);
    cont=0;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Muestra el código que tienes hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Comment: Construye una criba de Eratóstenes: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criba_de_Eratóstenes

Comment: El código ya lo agregué a la publicación, no sé si este bien hacerlo de esa manera.

Comment: @Yesid, no es que no conseguiste que se guarden los valores en el arreglo, tampoco lo intentaste (no en el código que posteas). Falta totalmente algo como `VecPrimos[indice]=valor`. Si seguís el consejo del algoritmo de la Criba de Eratóstenes vas a tener un mejor panorama, porque el propio vector de primos te sirve de filtro (básicamente el segundo `for` que hacés buscando módulos de cero funciona pero no está bien pensado, porque no necesitás dividir entre cada uno).

Comment: Entiendo, si lo intente de muchas maneras solo que no puse eso porque de cualquier manera las soluciones que había pensado no servían, por lo que solo deje lo que hasta el momento estaba funcionando, te agradezco mucho la ayuda, no tuve muy claro durante la explicación de los arreglos por eso me cuesta desarrollar los ejercicios, me podrías decir cómo corregir de mejor manera lo del segundo for?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único que te falta es guardar los valores de los números en primos en el array `VecPrimos[]` que has creado, y luego mostrarlos a tu antojo.
Te dejo un código donde (creo) que hace lo que buscas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int VecPrimos[5];
    int j=0;
    int cont=0;
    int i=0;
    int contador_primo=0;

    for(i=2;i<12;i++)
    {
        for(j=2;j<=i;j++)
            if(i%j==0)
                cont++;
            if(cont==1)
            {
                printf("\nEl numero primo es %d ",i);
                VecPrimos[contador_primo] = i;
                contador_primo++;
            }
            cont=0;
    }

    printf("\n\nNUMEROS PRIMOS EN ARRAY...\n");
    for(i=0 ; i<contador_primo ; i++)
        printf("%d ", VecPrimos[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias fue de mucha ayuda, me diste la idea de lo que justamente tenía mal, te agradezco infinitamente.